# Extracting a range of data in a string

Tags: c, memory, malloc, memory-address

Suppose I have:

```
char string[100] = "HelloMyNameIsBob";
```

and I want to extract the "MyName" part of the string and store it somewhere.

I tried doing this:

```
  char string[100] = "HelloMyNameIsBob";
  void *ptr = string;
  void *data_holder = malloc(6);
  memcpy(data_holder, string + 5, 6);
  printf("%c\n", *(char *)data_holder);
```

But I just print out the character "M".

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: `%c` prints a single character.  You didn't allocate enough space for a terminal null, so it is just as well you aren't printing a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
char string[100] = "HelloMyNameIsBob";
char *data_holder = malloc(7); // include space for null terminator!
memcpy(data_holder, string + 5, 6);
data_holder[6] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", data_holder);
free(data_holder);
```

Or much simpler, if you really just want to print and don't actually need to store the substring:

```
char string[100] = "HelloMyNameIsBob";
printf("%.6s\n", string + 5);
```

Comment: ahh thanks for the answer. But why is it giving me this warning?  warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%s\n", data_holder);

Comment: Because you are not writing the code the way I suggested.  You're apparently using `void*` as in your question instead of `char*` as in my answer.

Comment: Oh ya crap my bad, I see it now. Why won't C let you cast to a String?

Comment: @umdcoder: it will: you can do `(char*)data_holder` if you want to cast to a string.  But that's pointless, you should just use `char*` as the type, since it is known and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you are using `%c` instead of `%s` — please check.  You also need to pass a pointer for a string, not a character value.

Comment: Please do not use SMS-style abbreviations like 'pl' for 'please'.

Comment: OK it may be important.